# Django user creation return "Key 'username' not found in 'CustomUserForm'" for custom user

Tags: python, django

I have created a custom user for my django project. When I try to create a new user using the admin I ca not access the form and I get an error: `"Key 'username' not found in 'CustomUserForm'"`

My code is as follows:

models.py

```
from django.core import validators
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.http import urlquote
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/users/%s/" % urlquote(self.email)


    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name and the last name
        with a space between them.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns a short name for the user."
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        "Sends an email to the user."
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):

        now = timezone.now()

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_(u'The given username must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A form that creats a custom user with no privilages
    form a provided email and password.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    """
    A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import CustomUser
from .forms import CustomUserChangeForm, CustomUserCreationForm

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ( 'email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_filedsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

I cannot find any file containing `CustomUserForm` in the code. Is there anything about my set up that is wrong or something I could look at to deal with this issue?

**Edit:**
Here is the full traceback http://pastebin.com/YcZeM7yD

It seems that Django is looking for a form named (custom_user_model_name)Form in this instance CustomUserForm.

Comment: Post the whole trace back message so that we could find where the CustomUserForm  is.

Comment: I have posted the traceback as an edit. If I do not have `del self.fields['username']`in CustomUserCreationForm a form loads but it is not coming from the CustomUser model.

Comment: what version of django?

Comment: Nope, but the project is not finished and it seems to affect some of my past projects so I'll let you know as soon as I have a solution.

Comment: Yes this is solved the error was a typo in CustomUserAdmin add_filedsets to add_fieldsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a typo `add_filedsets`should be `add_fieldsets`.